# IIS FastCGI configuration for high concurrency

Tags: mysql, php, iis, fastcgi

I am hosting, on Windows Server 2022, a web application that makes regular ajax calls to a PHP backend.

The calls themselves are quite light, just pulling and pushing data from and to a MySQL db.

Over 1,000 users could be logged in concurrently (up to 10,000 in the near future). It doesn't seem to be an issue, until 100+ or so users log in concurrently, or near-concurrently.

I then get the server clogged with tens of stuck PHP-CGI processes.

Can anyone share advice on an adequate FastCGI config for this scenario?
I am - to say the least - confused by

Maxrequests vs Maxinstances
Activity timeout vs Idle timeout
Queue length
Rapid fails per minute vs Request timeout
Using tcp vs using Namedpipe

Thanks

Comment: Login counts are not of interest.  Queries per second is.  "nginx" is touted as fast; I have not tested it.  You need to discover the max number of we clients and connections to MySQL.  The latter is `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections'` and also `'Threads_running'`.  Do you have SSD?

Comment: Learn how to analyze why PHP web apps clogged with a profiler and then you can resolve stuck PHP-CGI processes and get what you wanted. Otherwise, you just get more of them.

Comment: @RickJames it's a VPS, and yes I believe it's running on SSD. I remember in the past, analysis of  that same application led to set max_connections to 600. However, SQL didn't seem to be the bottleneck. I was able to fire queries on workbench and get results instantly - while the clogging went on. It looks to me that PHP was somehow the culprit

Comment: @LexLi can you suggest a profiler that will work with IIS? All I have found seems to require either Nginx or Apache

Comment: @resle - PHP is limited to, or allowed to, a number of processes as specified by the web server.  Otherwise, my experience says that PHP is not the villain.  Sure, 600 MySQL connections is no problem -- but only if most are sitting idle.  When `Threads_running` exceeds 20, you have a problem.

Comment: @resle - And...  AJAX feels lightweight, but look at what it must go through -- client -> web server -> fire up PHP -> connect to database -> perform query -> unwind.  Realize that PHP is a process that is not sitting there waiting, but must be started up like any other process.